# Jquery field add code - Improvements in readability, compactness or efficiency

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I've worked hard on this code and it functions exactly as I wanted, but I've been told it is a little bit unreadable. My focus is to get the code as clean as possible, and have things as efficient as possible.

This is the code I am working with:
http://jsfiddle.net/xT5X5/6/

```
//latest
var maxFields = 10;

$('.form').on('click', '.add', function () {
      var value_src = $(this).prev();
       var container = $(this).parent().prev();
    if ($.trim(value_src.val()) !== '') {
        if (container.children().length < maxFields) {
            var value = value_src.val();
            var html = '<div class="line">' +
                '<input class="accepted" type="text" value="' + value + '" />' +
                '<input type="button" value="X" class="remove" />' +
                '</div>';

            $(html).appendTo(container);
            value_src.val('');
        } else {
            alert("You tried to add a field when there are already " + maxFields);
        }
    } else {
        alert("You didn't enter anything");
    }

})
    .on('click', '.remove', function () {
       $(this).parents('.line').remove();
});

$(".current").keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $(this).next("input").trigger("click");
    }
});

$(document).on("keyup",".accepted",function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $(this).closest('.copies').next().find(".current").focus();
    }
});
```

Can anyone give me any pointers on how I've done, and if there are any improvements that you can spot. Any feedback would be much appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: You are storing your application state in the HTML instead of keeping a JavaScript object and separating concerns ("requirements" for example is conceptually an array, not a list of DOM elements). This approach will make it very hard for your code to scale in terms of maintenance (Even atm, it's not very readable). Also, please post the code here as well.

Comment: Posted the code. I am adding in fields (I'm guessing thats what dom elements are applying to in this case) because it seemed a lot easier to submit in a form that way

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I disagree. I'd say state _should_ be stored in the DOM. That, I'd argue, is exactly how to separate concerns: JS controls behavior, the DOM contains the data, and CSS governs presentation. If the user is supposed to see what's going on, the data must necessarily be added to the DOM at some point, so I'd say keep it there to begin with. To get a "clean" JS array rather than a list of DOM elements, a simple jQuery `.map()` will suffice.

Comment: @Flambino I consider that a blunt _mistake_. You're developing a web application not a document. The state should be stored in JavaScript, in models like in any sensible GUI that does separation of concerns. This is exactly what the transition from static web pages to web applications is all about. Do you _honestly_ think querying your presentation is reasonable whenever you want to know your application's state? Storing HTML in JavaScript strings and having no separation of concerns? Storing application state in the DOM is dangerous and harmful. Separate the _right_ concerns.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Are we talking about submitting the array via ajax so that the results don't have to be stored in actual DOM field elements? The advantage of using fields is that I can easily edit the contents of each field after they have been added, otherwise I would probably just have text in printed above with no way to edit

Comment: @JamesWillson A lot of libraries like AngularJS and KnockoutJS provide bi-directional data-binding, for example (which is very similar to what you're doing) see http://learn.knockoutjs.com

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum If we're talking about a full-on everything-is-ajax-and-js _application_, then sure, throw Angular or KnockoutJS or anything else at it. Would I want to keep all state data in the DOM for such a project? No, of course not. But for this I'd do it. The DOM is beast, yes, but it's still a data model (and jQuery tames it). Libs like Knockout & Angular are neat, but they're also more code and more abstractions, and overkill in this case. All we're talking about is a neater HTML form.

Comment: @Flambino The DOM is not a beast. I think that the DOM is quite a nice abstraction to do presentation and it works which is why you see similar concepts for GUI like XAML in WPF or QML in QT. That's what it is though, presentation. Using data representing things - like JavaScript objects to represent well... data is not another abstraction - it's common sense. Storing application state in the presentation layer with all the markup is a bad technique that completely ignores how GUI is coded - it originates in an age where web pages were static. You don't need a framework to do it right!

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum And I still hold that the DOM is about data, not _necessarily_ presentation. Markup of any kind provides structure and semantics for data, and the DOM is the API: It is - among other things - a database you can query. (If we were talking about a simple XML file, I think you'd agree that it's just structured data, since XML by itself has no GUI.) It's a beast because it's not the nicest/fastest API for manipulating structured data, but it is an API nontheless. It also has a GUI component, but that doesn't invalidate its data modelling abilities.

Comment: @Flambino Right, and you can use XML for data all you want (although it's a data-exchange format for _documents_). However, HTML is _not_ just XML (or at all) and it's a specific mark up language for the presentation of web pages. Just because you can use something to store data doesn't mean that you should. You _can_ store data in custom attributes but it's a _horrible_ idea - just like you can create one giant string and slice it at specific places instead of using variables at all - doesn't mean it makes sense, it's simply not where it belongs. The DOM _is_ about data, presentation data.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum And I still disagree. If HTML was only about presentation, we'd still be using `<font>` tags, or `<i>` when we mean `<em>`. If anything HTML is _less_ about presentation nowadays, although you can treat it as merely that. Yes, you can do everything in JS, keep state there, and make sure the DOM reflects that state. Or you can consider the JS itself (in this simple case) practically stateless and wholly event-driven. The goal is DOM manipulation (adding/removing elements) so why complicate it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9407/discussion-between-benjamin-gruenbaum-and-flambino)

Comment: For the record, Benjamin and I kept arguing in the chat for a bit (we agreed to disagree), and ended up with these two fiddles: [His, using KnockoutJS](http://jsfiddle.net/kZZ5L/) and [mine, which is not too different from yours](http://jsfiddle.net/72BMm/). I used CoffeeScript for mine, but [here it is as JS](http://jsfiddle.net/e3FJB/1/)

Answer (score 1):

First of all there is a great article on [refactoring jQuery](http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2013/06/refactoring-js/?utm_source=javascriptweekly&utm_medium=email) by Jack Franklin.

Second is my solution that i came up with in last 2 hours(ocd kicked in). My solution is probably not right, because i still have a ton to learn and would appreciate any feedback !!

[Here fiddle with implementation](http://jsfiddle.net/Rusln/CsKzh/). Here is a short version of what is going on inside, as you can see i tried to refactor each action in it's own method:

```
// detail object that handles our form
var details = {
    maxFields: 10,
    form: "",
    init: function(el) {},
    bindEvents: function() {},
    appendCopy: function(event) {},
    removeCopy: function(event) {},
    createCopy: function(value) {},
    focusOnEnter: function(event) {},
    addCopyOnEnter: function(event) {},
    _isValueEmpty: function(val) {},
    _isMaxReached: function(copyContainer) {},
    _getParent: function(event){},
    _getCurrent: function(event){}
    _getCopyContainer: function(event){},
    _getValue: function(event){},   
};

// initialize our details object
    details.init(".form");
```

I think this could also be rewritten using `$.deferred` where each `deferred` would be responsible for tracking it's own progress (requirements,benefits,qualifications).